# Detect object only in middle

Tags: python

I have hundreds of images like that I attached (.png files).

I just want to work with the elements in the middle (it's always in the middle but with different sizes).

How do I remove off-center elements without cropping the image in python? It's not working...

[image]

```
def find_blobs_in_center(img, top_left_corner, bottom_right_corner):
    edges = cv.Canny(img, 30, 200)

    contour = cv.findContours(np.uint8(edges), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    is_in_center_contour = np.zeros(shape = len(contour[0]))

    rectangle_hor = np.arange(top_left_corner[0], bottom_right_corner[0])
    rectangle_ver = np.arange(top_left_corner[1], bottom_right_corner[1])
    
    for i, cnt in enumerate(contour[0]):
        buff = np.zeros(shape = (np.size(rectangle_hor), np.size(rectangle_ver)))
        for rec_idx_i, rec_val_i in enumerate(rectangle_hor):
            for rec_idx_j, rec_val_j in enumerate(rectangle_ver):
                buff[rec_idx_i, rec_idx_j] = cv.pointPolygonTest(cnt, (int(rec_val_i), int(rec_val_j)), True)
        is_in_center_contour[i] = np.any(buff > 0)
    
    center_contour = np.where(is_in_center_contour.flatten() > 0)

    return center_contour, contour

 center_contour, contour = find_blobs_in_center(img, top_left_corner, bottom_right_corner)
            mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype = 'uint8')
            cv.drawContours(mask, contour[0], center_contour[0][0], 255, -1)
            cut = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)
            cv.imwrite(f'Vorverarbeitung_2/Bearbeitung/cut/{galaxien_name}_cut.png', cut)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that using [`cv2.pointPolygonTest`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d48/tutorial_point_polygon_test.html). Here is an example for how to find a tuple of all the contours of all the blobs in an image, and return the index of the contour (blob) that's found at the center.

Edit: the center is defined by the top left and bottom right corners of a rectangle provided by the user to the function `find_blobs_in_image_ctr()`.

```
def find_blobs_in_image_ctr(img, top_left_corner, bottom_right_corner):
    '''
    Find the blob located near the center of the image img,
    whose width is defined by a rectangle whose top right 
    and bottom left corners are given by top_left_corner, bottom_right_corner
    '''
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect edges of blobs
    edges = cv2.Canny(img, 30, 200)

    # Find contours of blobs
    cnts = cv2.findContours(
                    np.uint8(edges),
                    cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # List to store the index values of he output to pointPolygonTest:
    is_in_center_contour = np.zeros(shape = len(cnts[0]))

    # Define center region:
    rectangle_hor = np.arange(top_left_corner[0], bottom_right_corner[0])
    rectangle_ver = np.arange(top_left_corner[1], bottom_right_corner[1])
    
    # Find which contours are at the center region:    
    for i, cnt in enumerate(cnts[0]):
        # Temporary array to store the result of the polygontest
        buff = np.zeros(shape = (np.size(rectangle_hor), np.size(rectangle_ver)))

        for rec_idx_i, rec_val_i in enumerate(rectangle_hor):
            for rec_idx_j, rec_val_j in enumerate(rectangle_ver):
                buff[rec_idx_i, rec_idx_j] = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, (rec_val_i, rec_val_j), True)
        
        is_in_center_contour[i] = np.any(buff > 0)
            
    # Print the indexes of the contours at the center, w.r.t. the tuple cnts:
    idxs_center_cnts = np.where(is_in_center_contour.flatten() > 0)

    return idxs_center_cnts, cnts

# Load image into grayscale
img = cv2.imread('/Users/liorr/Desktop/111.png')

top_left_ctr_corner = (270, 270)
bottom_right_ctr_corner = (280, 280)

idxs_center_cnts, cnts = find_blobs_in_image_ctr(img, top_left_ctr_corner, bottom_right_ctr_corner)
```

To draw the contour on an new image, use:

```
# Create a mask
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")

# drawContours() has an option to only draw the index of the
# contour you are interested in, i.e. idxs_center_cnts[0][0]
cv2.drawContours(mask, cnts[0], idxs_center_cnts[0][0], 255, -1)

# Save the blob to a new image using the mask we just created
newimg = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# Show the image
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
ax.imshow(mask)
plt.show()

# You can also write it to file:
cv2.imwrite('path/to/file', newimg)
```

Which should look like:

[image]

Or:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's because `cnts` is a tuple. I have edited the answer s.t. you will not get that warning.

Comment: I have added some more info about saving the new image to file

Comment: try changing `is_in_center_contour = np.zeros(shape = len(cnts))` to `is_in_center_contour = np.zeros(shape = len(cnts[0]))`

Comment: That's odd, it works for me. Try copying and pasting the code again, I have edited it a little.

Comment: Well, you should verify the blobs are indeed at the center of the image. For example, in the first image you have attached, no blobs are exactly at the center. The center is at (275, 275) and the blob does not include that point. You may, for example, want to include some region which you consider to be center instead of just `(int(imsize / 2), int(imsize / 2))`, and then iterate over this region.